# Eclipse plugin dev - No installed JREs satisfy this Execution Environment: "JavaSE-1.7". Launch aborted

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

In one of my Eclipses I got error when launching plugin as Eclipse application from plugin.xml Overview.

> No installed JREs satisfy this Execution Environment: "JavaSE-1.7".
>   Launch aborted.

**Where "JavaSE-1.7" could come from?**

In `MANIFEST.MF` there is

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

In Eclipse Preferences `Java -> Installed JREs` I have only jre6, and no other.

Sources at https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.debug/

Comment: Did you try adding Jdk1.7 or jre7 into Installed JRE?

Comment: I don't need to. I want to execute and build over 1.6

Comment: The Launch Configuration itself could be set to require 1.7.

Comment: It might be one of the plugin dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was something wrong with Eclipse itself (Eclipse 4.3.0 for Java/DSL developer on Windows 7), that next day it could not even start.

Solved by adding Java path in .ini

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/java.exe
```

Also check that JRE6 is also OK

```
-vm
C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/java.exe
```